# How do I idiomatically call a nullable lambda in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Given the following lambda:

```
val lambda: () -> Unit = null
```

Which of the following calls is idomatic to Kotlin for calling a nullable lambda?

```
lambda?.let { it() }
```

vs

```
lambda?.invoke()
```

Comment: This is gonna be up for personal opinions, but to give mine, the `let` usage here looks completely unnecessary, I always use just `?.invoke()`.

Comment: If we're onto personal opinions, why not just make the lambda non-null and say `() -> Unit = {}`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Let's ask Kotlin compiler:

```
 val lambda: (() -> Unit)? = null    
 lambda()
```

Compilers says:

```
Reference has a nullable type '(() -> Unit)?', use explicit '?.invoke()' to make a function-like call instead
```

So yeah, seems that `?.invoke()` is the way to go.

Although even this seems fine by me (and by compiler too):

```
 if (lambda != null) {
      lambda()     
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example:

```
fun takeThatFunction(nullableFun: (() -> Unit)?) {
    nullableFun?.let { it() }
}

takeThatFunction { print("yo!") }
```