# Null safety operator for function variable in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

In my Kotlin app I have nullable variable like this

```
private var myCallback : (() -> Unit)? = null
```

Is it possible to use null safety operator `?` to call it? This gives me a compilation error.

```
myCallback?()
```

I found only this ugly way for a call if it is not null

```
 if(myCallback != null)
     myCallback!!()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I idiomatically call a nullable lambda in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51733552/how-do-i-idiomatically-call-a-nullable-lambda-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call it as follows:

```
 myCallback?.invoke()
```

The `()` syntax on variables of function types is simply syntax sugar for the `invoke()` operator, which can be called using the regular safe call syntax if you expand it.