# What does this do: @Composable() () -> Unit?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

What does `@Composable() (() -> Unit)?` do? I see it defined as a parameter to OutlinedTextField in Jetpack Compose.
I know `@Composable() -> Unit` means you pass a composable that takes no parameter, but this one is strange and it does not even have a return type.

Answer (score 2):

`() -> Unit` is a type, just like `Int` for example. It is a function that takes no arguments and returns `Unit`. If you want to make a type `nullable`, you append `?` to the type, so `Int` becomes `Int?`.

With functional types, you can do `() -> Unit?`, but that is a `nonnull` function that returns `Unit?`. If you want the function itself to be `nullable`, you have to add parentheses: `(() -> Unit)?`.

This is what happens in `OutlinedTextField`. The actual declaration looks like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun OutlinedTextField(
    placeholder: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    ...

)
```

They simply wanted to make the `placeholder` argument `nullable`

Answer (score 0):

Some Composables take [nullable lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734014/5457853) for slots as in `OutlinedTextField`  as `label: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null` to give option for any slots that are not mandatory to be available while some others like Scaffold uses `topBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {}` [lambdas with empty default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784939/null-or-empty-lambda-as-default-value) in case you don't want to pass some of the slots defined in Composable.

Both notions can be used when you create a Composable with optional slots.

And `@Composable() (() -> Unit)` it's a function type and generally used in other Composable functions for ***[slot](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/basics#slot-based-layouts)*** api.

`@Composable` annotation resembles lets you access to other @Composale ui functions such as `Row`, `Column`, `Box`, etc., or non-ui functions such as `remember`, `LaunchEffect`, `SideEffect`, `DisposableEffect` or composer object. It resembles suspend function type which lets you call other suspending functions.

```
// function type
fun MyFun(myParam: suspend () -> Unit) { … }

// function type
fun MyFun(myParam: @Composable () -> Unit) { … }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261429/5457853

And a Composable function that is **not inline and returns unit** is considered as scope that's why Composable ui functions return unit. A scope is where recomposition.

https://dev.to/zachklipp/scoped-recomposition-jetpack-compose-what-happens-when-state-changes-l78

> For every non-inline composable function that returns Unit, the
> Compose compiler generates code that wraps the function’s body in a
> recompose scope. When a recompose scope is invalidated, the compose
> runtime will ensure the (entire) function body gets recomposed
> (reexecuted) before the next frame. Functions are a natural delimiter
> for re-executable chunks of code, because they already have
> well-defined entry and exit points.
>
> Foo’s body, Button’s body, the content lambda we pass to Button,
> Text’s body, all get their own recompose scopes.

Comment: I would like to know why they added the extra brackets `( )` after `Compose`:  @Composable`()` (() -> Unit). Are they optional? I mean  `@Composable() (() -> Unit) ==  @Composable () -> Unit`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, they both mean same thing but In TextField they actually use nullable lambdas which are placeholder: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null, and some composables use `@Composable () -> Unit = {}` which both are for optional slots or content Composables that are not supposed to be available in every implementation. You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/q/38784939/5457853, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51733552/how-do-i-idiomatically-call-a-nullable-lambda-in-kotlin/51734014#51734014. And in some Composables they use

Comment: Thank you Thracian. You have been very helpful.